# Show all child nodes from vocabulary

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

On board:

- Drupal 7
- Taxonomy
- Module Views

---

**Cars** (vocabulary)

- **Honda** (term)
- - Accord (node)
- - Civic (node)
- **Mazda** (term)
- - 3 (node)
- - 6 (node)
- **Mitsubishi** (term)
- - Lancer (node)
- - Pajero (node)

I'm using "Taxonomy term view" to display cars in categories.
I want to use same view to display all cars in all categories.

How can I do that?